# Component is returning a TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm receiving the following error message when running my app.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

I am importing Grid.js into my Index.js file as below. I am wanting Grid.js to display on the Index.js page however I'm receiving a TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined error.

**Grid.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Grid extends React.Component {
  state = {
    posts: [],
    isLoading: true,
    errors: null
  };

  getPosts() {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:1337/posts")
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          posts: response.data.posts,
          isLoading: false
        });
      })
      .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getPosts();
  }
    render(){
      const { isLoading, posts } = this.state;
      return <div>
        <div className="row">

          {!isLoading ? (
            posts.map(post => {
              const { _id, title, content } = post;
              return (


    <div className="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-6" key={_id}>
        <div className="list-item slick-item r list-hover mb-3">
          <div className="media text-hover-primary">
            <span className=" media-content"><i className="fas fa-images fa-4x text-muted"></i></span> 
            <div className="media-action media-action-overlay">
              <div className="row">

                <div className="w-100 text-center mt-2 h-1x">
                Misc Meta Properties
                </div>

                <div className="w-100 text-center mt-4">
                  <a className="btn btn-sm btn-outline-light btn-rounded mx-3" href="{item.url}">View Type</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="list-content text-center">
            <div className="list-body">
                      <a className="list-title title" href="{item.url}">{title}</a>
                      <a className="list-subtitle d-block text-muted subtitle text-small ajax" href="{item.url}">Brand</a> 
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
</div>  );
            })
          ) : (
            <p>

            </p>

          )}

            </div></div>

    }
  }
export default Grid;
```

**Index.js (Pages/index.js)**

```
import Header from '../components/Header'
import Grid from '../components/Grid'
import Welcome from '../components/Welcome'
import Footer from '../components/Footer'
import "../style.css"

const Index = () => (
  <div>
    <body className="bg-dark">
    <Header></Header>
    <Welcome></Welcome>
    <div className="container">
        <Grid/>
        <Footer/>
    </div>
    </body>
  </div>
)

export default Index
```

I'm successfully able to read and display data when using the **getInitialProps** function from NextJs. However, I am wanting this API to sit in a nice component file that I can call instead of having it all on the Index.js page and then iterating over it with *this.props.title*, etc.

Any ideas?

Edit:

**From the console:**
   [{"id":1,"title":"test","content":"test","created_at":1556521391304,"updated_at":1556521391312},{"id":2,"title":"test","content":"test","created_at":1556521394698,"updated_at":1556521394702}]

From the API directly (Strapi), when browsing to http://localhost:1337/posts/
    [{"id":1,"title":"test","content":"test","created_at":1556521391304,"updated_at":1556521391312},{"id":2,"title":"test","content":"test","created_at":1556521394698,"updated_at":1556521394702}]

Comment: Can you log the value of `response.data.posts`?

Comment: make sure you are getting array of values in response.data.posts

Comment: Yep, it's showing up in console.log

Comment: try doing the condition `posts && posts.map`

Comment: @MattCohen, can you post the log value in your post?

Comment: No longer getting the error message, still able to display it in console but not in the component.

Comment: [{"id":1,"title":"test","content":"test","created_at":1556521391304,"updated_at":1556521391312},{"id":2,"title":"test","content":"test","created_at":1556521394698,"updated_at":1556521394702}]

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting `posts` from your server response, or you do bad handling of this response.

If you don't want to get "error" when server fails you can swap from `{!isLoading ? (` to `{(post && post.length) ? (`.

Answer (score 1):

Before going to use map function make sure that your data should return array and it shout not null check at map function level like

```
render(){
  const { isLoading, posts } = this.state;
  return <div>
    <div className="row">

      {!isLoading ? (
        posts !=null&&posts.length>0&&posts.map(post => {
          const { _id, title, content } = post;
          return (


<div className="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-6" key={_id}>
    <div className="list-item slick-item r list-hover mb-3">
      <div className="media text-hover-primary">
        <span className=" media-content"><i className="fas fa-images fa-4x text-muted"></i></span> 
        <div className="media-action media-action-overlay">
          <div className="row">

            <div className="w-100 text-center mt-2 h-1x">
            Misc Meta Properties
            </div>

            <div className="w-100 text-center mt-4">
              <a className="btn btn-sm btn-outline-light btn-rounded mx-3" href="{item.url}">View Type</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="list-content text-center">
        <div className="list-body">
                  <a className="list-title title" href="{item.url}">{title}</a>
                  <a className="list-subtitle d-block text-muted subtitle text-small ajax" href="{item.url}">Brand</a> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

);
            })
          ) : (

```
        </p>

      )}

        </div></div>

}
```

Answer (score 1):

in render() method you used posts.map right, what happend in react it first time it checks the render method, first time post is a empty array, so use the below code in your render method.

```
render(){
      var { posts } = this.state;
      var displayContent = !posts?[]:posts.map((data,index) => {
                            return {data.title}
                            })
```

after this use main return method write your HTML code, just use {displayContent} where you want its a easy way to do it........

the above error you specified it occurs because post[] 1st time its empty..so use above code it works...

when you're free go through the below link React Life cycle Methods.

[Life Cycle Methods](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, still not working unfortunately.

Comment: can you upload the screenshot please, that will help me to find out.

Answer (score 0):

Update **!isLoading ? (posts.map(** code with below code:

```
!isLoading && posts && Array.isArray(posts) ? posts.map(...) : ""
```

Answer (score 0):

i assume you are using nextjs. Which mean on init page load is from server rather than client. In nextjs there is a method call `getinitialprops`, which get any data and create props.